# How to add multiple images to a single record in SQL Server using asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a site and one of its requirement is to add multiple images to a single column of database along with other details.

This is the screenshot of my webform:

[image]

and this is my database table:

[image]

But I am confused about adding multiple images in a specific field of one row. Is it possible that a single record can have a field with multiple images stored in it? Please suggest a good solution to this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Create a different table call Images, have a link from this table to that one (the Images column became foreign key to that table).

Comment: The only good solution would be to add a new table for the images, that will contain a foreign key to this table, and a `varbinary(max)` column to store a single image. Anything other then that will cause problems.

Comment: Yes I know, I can do it this way. Thank you.. I think I have to do it this way only.

Answer (score 1):

You can store multiple files together in a single blob or stream by using MIME Multipart formatting. See this RFC: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Note that using a separate table with one record per image/file is a better overall solution because there is a large overhead in extracting files from a Multipart blob, making it slow and inefficient... so don't store files larger than a few kilobytes.